# Re-assigning objects causes memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm slowly learning Obj-C so I'm sorry if this is a noob question.

In my app, I have a class called `Object` that simply holds a bunch of variables.

```
Object *object = [[Object alloc] init];
```

I create an instance of this class in a Static Singleton object within my program. I noticed however that whenever I create a new instance of it (I have a button that calls the `resetObject` method) my memory usage increases.

```
// DataBank.h
 Object *object;

// DataBank.m
- (void)resetObject {
   object = [[Object alloc] init];
  }
```

I'm guessing that this is probably due to the old instance of Object not being deallocated? I tried deallocating it but I'm given an error that it isn't allowed with ARC. Is there any way around this?

Comment: no... there is no leak in the code above. (assuming Object [which we'd need to see] itself is fine)

Comment: what is leaking and when

Comment: The problem is that, whenever I call [DataBank resetObject], my memory usage increases by 1.5MB

Comment: yes, so use instruments and figure out what object leaks ... (btw. advice: don't call your class Object. it is confusing;))

Comment: Instruments? What do you mean?

And yeah, I'm not haha. I'm just referencing to it as Object here so it makes my explanation clearer :)

Comment: Maybe there's a retain cycle, or something strongly references your object somewhere else. Anyway, in your code shown, there's nothing that could cause this. The problem is in other code you didn't show.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try to modify your code as follows?

```
// DataBank.m
- (void)resetObject {
   if (object)
   { [object release];}
   object = [[Object alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: He's using ARC, so no release allowed.